# Oracle installation script execution privileges: "oracle is not in the sudoers file"

Tags: installation, root, scripts, oracle

I'm currently installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu 10.10

It had been asked to execute some scripts as "root" while installation.

I'm doing:

```
oracle@sergio:/u01/app/oraInventory$ sudo sh orainstRoot.sh
```

And got:

```
[sudo] password for oracle: 
oracle is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

How could I actually run these scripts if I logged under `oracle` user with "root" privileges?

thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I do not have experience in Oracle installation, the error message makes me think, this might work:

```
sudo adduser oracle admin
```

This will add the user 'oracle' to the admin group, and the 'admin' group is in the sudoers file by default.

Edit: you need to run this command as the very first user of your system (the one you had to name during install), or as a root (in this case you do not need the sudo part).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the DBA would request the system administrator to run the script requiring root access.   It is uncommon to grant the oracle user sudo access.  This violates the separation of privileges.

Run the script using sudo from the account you usually use to install packages and do other things that require root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle user only for accessing Oracle Database and installation files.
Please follow below article.

[Installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu](http://sqlandplsql.com/2011/12/02/installing-oracle-11g-on-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't start the installation as the "oracle" user. Use `sudo` from your current desktop user or use root (without `sudo`).

Than in your case

```
oracle@sergio:/u01/app/oraInventory$ sudo sh orainstRoot.sh
```

should be started from sergio user:

```
sergio@sergio:/u01/app/oraInventory$ sudo sh ./orainstRoot.sh
```